# Knockoutjs hasFocus on a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, modal-dialog

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but my hasFocus binding on a modal doesn't work. I looked at this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JasperTey/CRnXW/) posted by @jasper-tey but when I pulled it out of a frame and wrote it as a standalone HTML page it wouldn't work.

I debugged the setFocus function and confirmed that the isFocused value is being set in the model. The binding seems to be correct and the parser isn't yelling at me. Yet the modal doesn't get focus in my code but it seems to work fine in the jsfiddle example. Any pointers on what I am missing would be most appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Input-focus in a Modalized Knockout Template</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
        <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>

  <style id="compiled-css" type="text/css">
      .container {
    padding: 10px;
}
  </style>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <h4>Input-focus in a Bootstrap Modal</h4>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch modal</button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                     <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" data-bind="template: { name: 'bodyTemplateA'}"></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: setFocus">Set Focus</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script id="bodyTemplateA" type="text/html">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: name, hasFocus: isFocused" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Type</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: type" />
    </div>
</script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).load(function(){

        function mainModel (){
                var self = this;
                self.name =  ko.observable("Blue border when in focus");
                self.type =  ko.observable();

                self.header =  ko.observable("This is a modal");
                self.body =  ko.observable('bodyTemplateA');

                self.isFocused =  ko.observable(false);

                self.setFocus = function() {
                        data.isFocused(true);
                }

        }

        var data = new mainModel();  
        ko.applyBindings(data);

        $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
            data.isFocused(true);
        });


        });

  </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the code and updated the knockoutjs import, from version 2.2.1 to version 3.1.0 and it worked.

The code that i changed:

```
        var data = {
                // var self = this;
                name:  ko.observable(),
                type:  ko.observable(),

                header: ko.observable("This is a modal"),
                body: ko.observable('bodyTemplateA'),

                isFocused:  ko.observable(false),

                setFocus: function() {
                        data.isFocused(true);
                },

        }

        ko.applyBindings(data);

        $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
            data.isFocused(true);
        });
```

Although I think the library version is the one causing trouble.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I could use a jquery selector to set focus on the first textbox but I was trying to do this using knockoutjs data bindings and wondering why it works on the linked jsfiddle example but not in my code.

Comment: @bswat I've updated the answer to try not to use jquery

Comment: Thanks! It did not occur to me that this may have been due to the knockoutjs library version.